# Access home folder in external hard drive

Tags: permissions, external-hdd, cloning

I recently changed from an HDD to SSD on my machine. The HDD had a dual boot with Windows and Linux. The Windows system had no password, the Linux had a password.

When putting the HDD in an enclosure and opening on my machine (with the SSD), it can read the Windows partition fine. However for the Linux partition, the home folder comes up empty, despite file manager indicating it has the same amount of free space as it had when it was still the drive being used on my machine - indicating the home folder does have files.

How can I access these files/change permissions on the drive to allow the files to be viewable?

Comment: Did you have a separate partition mounted as /home on the old disk ?

Comment: No, everything was on the same partition

Comment: @SorenA the current /home and old /home have different filesystems. current is ext4, old is btrfs

Comment: I answered the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/709197/access-home-folder-in-external-hard-drive/709202#709202).